# How to use setOnKeyListener && radio buttons for temperature converter in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to write a program that converts temperatures. I am using two radio buttons to choose from(cel to F & F to Cel). My app is working except i can't choose the other radio button. It force closes my app. Not sure why. Maybe i have to set my other button to false if the other one is clicked?
    package com.example.temperatureconverter;

```
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.*;

public class Calculate extends Activity 
{
private EditText in, out;
//******************onCreate()*****************************
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) 
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate);

    in = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    out =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.results);

    in.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {   

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            double num, calc;
            if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.radio1)
                {
                    num = Double.parseDouble(in.getText().toString());
                    calc = ((9.0/5.0) * num + 32);
                    out.setText(String.valueOf(calc));
                }
                else
                {
                    num = Double.parseDouble(in.getText().toString());
                    calc = (num - 32) * (9.0/5.0);
                    out.setText(String.valueOf(calc));
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
//******************buttonClick()*****************************  
public void buttonClick(View v)
{
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton)v).isChecked();
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.radio1:
            if(checked)
            {

            };

            break;
        case R.id.radio2: 
            if(checked)
            {

            };
            break;
    }
}
}
```

here is my layout file named calculate.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<RadioGroup 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/celsius"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:checked="true"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/farenheit"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"/>    
 </RadioGroup>
 <EditText android:id="@+id/input"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:hint="@string/input"/>
 <EditText android:id="@+id/results"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:inputType="number"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can change your results EditText to a TextView, since the user is not supposed to change its value.

Comment: Take care because you have buttonClicked on your XML and buttonClick() on your code.

Comment: I'm supposed to have results as an EditText. So if I include onClick="buttonClicked" in my layout XML file can I use setOnKeyListener? Or do I need to erase that?

Comment: You can use it anyway. But I Would have a Button that when clicking it, it would make the translation.